# AngularJS : Select doesn't change selected option on change of bound scope variable

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have a select control. Its options are generated dynamically from scope's array of objects.  On app init I want to select a specific option by changing bound variable on the scope.

It doesn't work when select's ng-option returns full object. However, it works when select's ng-option returns string.

Is it angular bug or I do something wrong?

HTML:

```
<div ng-controller="selectCtrl" ng-app>
    Doesn't work when select's ngModel value is object:<br />
    <select ng-model="valueObject" ng-options="o.label for o in options"></select><br />
    <pre>{{valueObject | json}}</pre>

    Works when select's ngModel value is string:<br />
    <select ng-model="valueString" ng-options="o.value as o.label for o in options"></select>
    <pre>{{valueString | json}}</pre>
```

JS:

```
function selectCtrl($scope) {    
   $scope.options = [
       {label: 'a', value: '1', someId: 333},
       {label: 'b', value: '2', someId: 555}
   ];    
   $scope.valueObject = {label: 'a', value: '1', someId: 333};
   $scope.valueString = '1';
};
```

JS Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/apuchkov/FvsKW/6/

Answer (score 10, accepted):

**"Track by" expression** has to be used to make example in my question work. More details here: http://leoshmu.wordpress.com/2013/09/11/making-the-most-of-ng-select/

Updated JsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/apuchkov/FvsKW/9/

HTML

```
<div ng-controller="selectCtrl" ng-app>
    Doesn't work when select's ngModel value is object:<br />
    <select ng-model="valueObject" ng-options="o.label for o in options"></select><br />
    <pre>{{valueObject | json}}</pre>

    Does work when select's ngModel value is object AND 'track by' expression is used:<br />
    <select ng-model="valueObject" ng-options="o.label for o in options track by o.value"></select><br />
    <pre>{{valueObject | json}}</pre>
</div>
```

JS

```
function selectCtrl($scope) {    
    $scope.options = [
        {label: 'a', value: '1', someId: 333},
        {label: 'b', value: '2', someId: 555}
    ];    
    $scope.valueObject = {label: 'a', value: '1', someId: 333};
};
```

Answer (score 5):

The key is that objects with the same keys and values are not equal to each other ([ref ES 5.1 Specification 11.9.6](http://es5.github.io/#x11.9.6)):

```
// Return true if x and y refer to the same [in-memory] object.
// Otherwise, return false.
> var one = {label: 'a', value: '1', someId: 333}
> var two = {label: 'a', value: '1', someId: 333}
> one === one
true
> two === two
true
> one === two
false
> one == two
false
```

Change `$scope.valueObject = { /* similar object */ }` to `$scope.valueObject = $scope.options[0]` and everything should work.

Comment: You right, just checked source code of angular.js and it uses "===" to select check if option should be selected. I would expect it to use angular.equals instead.

Answer (score 0):

It should work for such controller:

```
function selectCtrl($scope) {
   $scope.options = [
       {label: 'a', value: '1', someId: 333},
       {label: 'b', value: '2', someId: 555}
   ];    
   $scope.valueObject = $scope.options[ 0 ];
};
```